# Why is Rails 3.1 randomly serving older vs newer versions of my app's templates? (dev mode, cache disabled)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm running my rails 3.1 app in development mode with cache disabled, but it's acting like cache is enabled.

I can go to a page in the app, see one version, then refresh over and over, watching it randomly switch between the previous version and new version of the footer, for example :(

Why is Rails doing this and how can I turn it off?

Comment: It seems like it could be cache related but cache is currently disabled in environment settings. :( Sometimes if I refresh it changes back to the correct (newer) version... then if i refresh again, it's back to the old version.... what the hell....

Comment: In order to make sure that it is cash related, test it in another browser and see if the same thing happens or not. Or clear the cache of your browser as well as the `tmp` folder of your Rails app.

Comment: I've tried clearing all cache on this computer as well as trying other browsers.

It would take hours for my ftp program to delete the /tmp/ folder cache contents, so I just renamed the folder to tmp_OLD. Does that work?

Comment: Yes that should also work. Did it resolve the problem?

Comment: Can you post the content of `development.rb` fro `config` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I am using thin web server and it turns out that my developer was just kinda vague about it. They said they weren't sure why it was happening but it turns out it just needed to be restarted. :/

In case anyone who was a noob like me is wondering how to restart their thin server:

```
 thin restart -C config /path-to/your-app/config/thin.yml
```

...for example. And make sure you have that C capitalized. If it's lowercase it doesn't mean the same thing.